# int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Category'

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the error below when trying to load my Category. The value posted is '1' and exists in the DB,

```
TypeError at /events/add/

int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Category'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/new/
Django Version:     1.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Category'

Exception Location:     /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 537
Python Executable:  /Users/user/Documents/workspace/RoseBud/django-env/bin/python
```

views.py

```
 category = Category.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['category'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like the object returned by `form.cleaned_data['category']` is a category object, not a number.

If that's the case, just do `category = form.cleaned_data['category']`

print it to be sure.

Comment: yes that was it. So is that default behavior? When I looked in the requested vars being passed the category input was = 1 so does Django auto get the object for me or something?

Comment: haven't worked a lot with forms but I would guess that it automatically passes the id (because how are you going to have an object as an input value) and then parses it on the server side

Comment: exactly. When you use a ForeignKeyField in forms, django uses a widget that returns the pk (primary key) field of the related object. The forms.Form class will take care to return the related object automatically.